# What is a set? And what does "a for a in i" do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across these constructs and I'm not quite sure what they do. Can someone explain?

```
setx = set([a for a in i])    
sety = set([y for y in j])
```

Code, for context

```
a = int(input())  
for i in range(a):  
    i = (input())  
    j = (input())  
    setx = set([a for a in i])    
    sety = set([y for y in j])  
    if setx.intersection(sety) == set():  
        print("NO")  
    else:  
        print("YES")
```

Comment: What do you think it does?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Please fix your indentation too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[a for a in i]` is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's basically a concise way to make a list.

They can be really useful, or they can be source of much unreadable code, or both. The full syntax is

```
[f(i) for i in iterator if conditional(i)]
```

examples:

List of squares: `[i**2 for i in range(n)]`

List of squares not divisible by 5: `[i**2 for i in range(n) if i**2 % 5 =! 0]`

And as for *set*: [Set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) is a very useful data type in python. It's basically a dictionary without the values. All elements must be unique and hashable, and sets do not store order, but checking to see if an object is in a set is not dependent on the length of the set.

In this case, your code is probably using sets to make figuring out if the two inputs share any commonalities faster and easier to write.

(Also, finally: Uh, as posted, I don't really know what your code does, but I can be pretty sure it doesn't what it wants to. If I were to rewrite it, it'd be something like

```
a = int(input()) 
setx = set() #initializing empty sets
sety = set() 
for _ in range(a):  #underscore often used when you don't care about what you're iterating over, just that you iterate a certain amount of times.
    setx.add(input()) #Previously, you'd just get the last input
    sety.add(input()) #I doubt that's what you wanted 
if setx.intersection(sety): #no need to compare to empty set. if set() will evaluate as false  
    print("NO")  
else:  
    print("YES")
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Set is build-in data type: a collection of unordered unique elements, strong on unique. 
For more specifics see the amazing python Docs: For example See [https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set]

So using *set()* over that list comprehension it is removing duplicates from the list.